# Cannot create an instance of FluentNHibernate.Automapping.AutoMapping Namespace.Class[T] because Type.ContainsGenericParameters is true

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

Here is the error i'm getting

```
CookBook.Tests.CategoryRepository_Fixture.Can_update_category:
FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException : An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.


  ----> FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException : An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.


  ----> System.ArgumentException : Cannot create an instance of FluentNHibernate.Automapping.AutoMapping`1[CookBook.Repository.Repository`1[T]] because Type.ContainsGenericParameters is true.
```

here is my Category object

```
public class Category
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

here is my test class

```
[TestFixture]
class CategoryRepository_Fixture
{
    private ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    private RecipeConfiguration _configuration;

    private readonly Category[] _categories = new[]
    {
        new Category{Name="Dinner"},
        new Category{Name="Breakfast"},
        new Category{Name="Lunch"},
        new Category{Name="Breakfast"}
    };

    private void CreateInitialData()
    {
        using (ISession session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            foreach (var category in _categories)
            { session.Save(category); }
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void TestFixtureSetUp()
    {
        _configuration = new RecipeConfiguration();
        _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlCeConfiguration.Standard.ShowSql().ConnectionString("Data Source=CookBook.sdf"))
            .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Category>(_configuration)))
            .ExposeConfiguration(config => new SchemaExport(config).Execute(false, true, false))
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void SetupContext()
    {
        CreateInitialData();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Can_add_new_category()
    {
        Category cat = new Category { Name = "Dessert" };
        IRepository<Category> repository = new Repository<Category>();
        repository.Add(cat);

        using (ISession session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            var fromDb = session.Get<Category>(cat.Id);
            Assert.IsNotNull(fromDb);
            Assert.AreNotSame(cat, fromDb);
            Assert.AreEqual(cat.Name, fromDb.Name);
        }
    }
```

Here is the repository class

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    #region IRepository Members

    public void Add(T obj)
    {
        using(ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            session.Save(obj);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?  is it not possible to use a generic repository? because I have about 4 objects that all use the same repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is, that automapping tries to automap your repository, that it shouldn't map, only entities. your `RecipeConfiguration` should tell FNH which classes to map.

```
public bool ShouldMap(Type type)
{
    return type.In(typeof(Category), typeof(Foo));
}
```

or

```
public bool ShouldMap(Type type)
{
    return type.Namespace == "MyNamespace.Mappings"
}
```

or

```
AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Category>(t => t.Namespace == "MyNamespace.Mappings"))
```